# How do I run a command with su permission

Tags: android

I'm trying to mount my system read and write but I keep getting a permissions denied when I run the command
busybox mount -o remount,rw /system from terminal

Comment: Do you have a rooted device?

Answer (score 0):

To run a command as superuser, prepend it with `su`.

E.g. `su screenrecord` or `su dumpsys`

Comment: I'm relatively new at this so if you could give me an example will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo something` or run the `su` command to change your terminal privileges.

Example:

```
user$ whoami
user
user$ mount ...
Access denied
user$ su
(SuperSU box appears)
root# whoami
root
root# mount ...
(mount OK)
```

Comment: Please note many Android environments even with busybox don't have `sudo something` command due to security reasons.